# javascript hide div on page load until if statement condition selects div

Tags: javascript, html, hide, show

Ive got two div's on a webpage, which need to be hidden from page load until the if statement in the script block dictates when the div is to be displayed..is this possible and how can it be done? 
i have a jQuery linked but what i've tried doesnt work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-color: #3da9cd;
            background:url('background.jpg');
            height: 50%;
            width: 50%;
            margin:0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow:auto;
        }
        h1 {
            font-size: 34px;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #000000;
        .hidden { display: none; }
        .shown {display:block;}
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">


function WinLose()
{
    $("#win").hide();
$("#lose").hide();
    var x=document.getElementById("demo");
    x=x.innerHTML=Math.floor((Math.random()*5)+1);

    if (x==5)
    {
        $('#win').show()

    }
    else 
    {
        $('#lose').show()
    }

}

</script>

</head>
<body>


<p id="demo"></p>

<button onclick="WinLose()">Try it</button>

<!-- Win element -->
        <div id="win" class="hidden">Congratulations! You have won a prize. *UNIQUE CODE* Collect your prize from the Customer Services desk</div>

        <!-- The losing image div -->
        <div id="lose" class="hidden">Sorry, you have not won. Better luck next time</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can we see some code, please... that way we know what methods you're trying to use and we can help from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the visibility of the divs using css `display` property like so:

```
.hidden { display: none; }
```

and your divs like so:

```
<div class="hidden">first div</div>
<div class="hidden">second div</div>
```

and then with your, js either remove the `hidden` class or `$.show()`.

Comment: Thanks, tried this so far but it still shows all text, i've added the code so far to the question

Comment: You seem to have gotten the h1 `}`misplaced.

Comment: ALL BECAUSE OF A } THANKYOU :D

Answer (score 2):

CSS:

```
.DIV_CLASS{
    display:none;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(some statment){
        $('.DIV_CLASS').show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You either shows the div in the if statement or use `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()` to periodically check for whatever if statement sets.